# Generating random letters in a 10*10 matrix

Tags: python

[enter image description here][1]

How to create a 10*10 matrix that will generate random letters, only using them once and never going outside the matrix. I know my while loop and for statement at the bottom is whats tripping me up? Trying to find the x and y values in the while loop as well. Suppose to look like picture above?

```
import random

    N = 10

    FILLER = '.'



    line = []

    for i in range(N):

    line.append(FILLER)



    a=[]

    for i in range (N):

            line = line[:]

            a.append(line)


    x = 0

    y = 0

    letter = 'A'

    a[x][y] = letter



    letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)



    while (letter <= 'Z'):

        x =

        y =

        if (a[x][y] == FILLER):


    for i in range(N):

        print(' '.join(a[i]))


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZRvW.png
```

Comment: what does "only using them once" mean?

Comment: A 10x10 matrix has 100 fields, filling all fields and still use every letter not more than once seems like a tough task!

Comment: Do you characters, or letters?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't studied your code but if you want a 10x10 matrix containing random letter from EN language (without repeating any letter), you can use the below code.

```
import numpy as np
import string
import random

alpha=list(string.ascii_uppercase)

a=[]
for x in range(100):
    choice=random.choice(alpha)
    if choice in a:
        a.append('.')
    else:
        a.append(choice)

arr=np.array(a)
res_arr=arr.reshape([10,10])

print(res_arr)
```

Output:

```
[['S' 'B' 'N' 'P' '.' 'A' 'G' 'O' '.' 'I']
 ['U' 'Z' 'F' '.' 'Q' '.' 'K' 'C' 'H' 'X']
 ['L' '.' '.' 'E' 'T' '.' 'M' '.' 'J' 'V']
 ['.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' 'Y']
 ['.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.']
 ['.' 'R' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.']
 ['.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.']
 ['.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.']
 ['.' '.' '.' '.' '.' 'D' '.' '.' '.' '.']
 ['.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.']]
```

A few things to note here:

1) I haven't seeded the `random`. You can do that if you want to generate same matrix every time, to do that use:

```
random.seed(10) #replace 10 with integer of your choice (use this after generating alpha)
```

2) I have left `res` as a numpy array. If you want it as list use:

```
res_arr=arr.reshape([10,10]).tolist() #replace this with the res_arr declaration in the above code
```

Comment: Not that the rules of the puzzle are clear, but your algorithm can leave out letters -- you can see it in your example output where only 25 of the 26 letters have been used.  Given the ratio of matrix elements to letters, we'd really expect to use them all up.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But as you said the rules aren't clear. If what you are saying is true. Then little bit of tweaking in the code will do. As of now I am leaving it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shuffle()` from the `random` module:

```
from random import shuffle
import numpy as np

l = [n for n in range(65,91)]+[46 for n in range(74)]
shuffle(l)
print([[chr(a) for a in i] for i in np.reshape(l,(10,10))])
```

Output:

```
[['L', 'Q', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'V', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['K', '.', 'N', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'F', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'M', '.', '.'],
 ['.', 'D', '.', '.', 'T', '.', '.', 'J', 'P', '.'],
 ['I', '.', 'Z', '.', 'B', '.', '.', 'H', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'C', 'U', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'E', 'A'],
 ['R', '.', '.', 'Y', '.', 'G', 'W', '.', '.', '.']]
```

---

EXTRA:

This look nicer :)

```
from random import shuffle
import numpy as np

l = [n for n in range(65,91)]+[46 for n in range(74)]
shuffle(l)

for i in np.reshape(l,(10,10)):
    print(' '.join([chr(a) for a in i]))
```

Output:

```
. . . . O N X F . .
. . . C . T K . W .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . Z . V . . . .
. M . . E . A S . .
J P . . H . . . R .
. Q . . . . . . . .
. G . . . I . . B D
. . . L Y . . . . .
U . . . . . . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing clever, taking it step by step and making sure we can resize the matrix and still work:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as letters
from random import randrange

SIZE = 10
EMPTY = ' '

matrix = [[EMPTY for _ in range(SIZE)] for _ in range(SIZE)]

for letter in letters[:min(SIZE ** 2, len(letters))]:  # in case we're using a tiny matrix
    while True:
        x, y = randrange(0, SIZE), randrange(0, SIZE)

        if matrix[x][y] == EMPTY:  # don't over write existing letter
            matrix[x][y] = letter
            break

print(*matrix, sep='\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
['X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Y', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', 'J', ' ', ' ', 'E', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'I', ' ', ' ', 'N']
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'S', ' ', 'B', 'F', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Q', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['A', 'M', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'C', 'D', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T']
['U', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'R', ' ', ' ', 'K', ' ', 'W']
[' ', ' ', 'V', ' ', 'L', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'H', 'P']
[' ', ' ', 'Z', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'G']
>
```